# Passing a query into Django test

Tags: django, testing

I want to test a view of my Django application.

```
def search(request):
    query = request.GET.get('query')
    query_lower = query.lower()
    list_name = re.split("[- ’? ; , ' . : ' ' " " ]",query_lower)    
    stripped_query = [strip_accents(x) for x in list_name]     
    clean_query =[word for word in stripped_query if word not in stopwords]    

    match_list = []
    for x in Product.objects.all():
        match = 0        
        for y in clean_query:
            if y in x.name or y in x.brand:
                match += 1
                if match == len(clean_query):
                    match_list.append(x.id)                
            else:
                pass

    if not query:
        products_list= Product.objects.all()        
    else:        
        products_list = Product.objects.filter(id__in=match_list)

    context = {
        'products': products_list,            
    }
    return render(request, 'finder/search.html', context)
```

I did create some products in my tests.py with `setup` and I want to test if I have a 200 status code if on of those products is searched:

```
def test_Search(self):
        self.response = self.client.post(reverse(('finder:search'), {'query':'gazpacho'}))  
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)
```

I got a `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. 
So, how I am supposed to pass my query into my test for it to be run?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
class TestKlass(...):
    def test_Search(self):
        url = reverse('finder:search')
        url_with_param = "{}?{}".format(url, 'query=gazpacho')
        self.response = self.client.post(url_with_param)
        self.assertEqual(self.response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your view handles `GET`-parameters so the request itself is a `GET`-request.

In your test you are sending a post, which should be a `get` accordingly:

```py
self.client.get(url, {'query': '...'})
```

Parameters are passed as the second argument for `get()`/`post`.

See more in the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.get).

In your case most likely (without having the full trace of the error) your error is the way you are calling `reverse()` in your test.

The second argument passed to that function is `urlconf`. From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse):

> The urlconf argument is the URLconf module containing the URL patterns to use for reversing. By default, the root URLconf for the current thread is used.